# How can I get / set an extended property from a contact using Microsoft's EWS API?

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I think I'm creating it properly, like as follows. c is a Contact, and I'm just trying to store a unique identifier considering that ItemId which is provided by EWS isnt static...

```
propertySetId = System.Guid.NewGuid();
// Create a definition for the extended property.
ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedPropertyDefinition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Common, "itemGUID", MapiPropertyType.String);
c.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, propertySetId.ToString());
c.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```

When I try to pull this back out when searching for the contact based on something else, like first name, I'm getting a null returned. I'm trying to get the value by:

```
foreach (Item c in findResults.Items)
{
      foreach(ExtendedProperty extendedProperty in c.ExtendedProperties)
      {
            if(extendedProperty.PropertyDefinition.Name == "itemGUID")
            {
                  results[i] = extendedProperty.Value.ToString();
            }
      }
}
```

EDIT: code for findResults

```
List<SearchFilter> searchFilters = new List<SearchFilter>();
searchFilters.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(itemGUID, value));
//can be more filters here depending on situation
SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, searchFilters.ToArray());
findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, filter, view);
```

Comment: Please share the code for how you get `findResults` - specifically the `FindItems` method call parameters.

Comment: Please include the `view` param assignment - I think this is where the issue lies.

Comment: All I do for the view before that is: ItemView view = new ItemView(50);

Comment: see answer below...you just need a bit more configuration to retrieve your custom property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the `PropertySet` in the `ItemView` to tell EWS what properties to include when you search using `FindItems`. If you don't include it in your `ItemView` it won't be available for reading.The alternative approach is to use the `Contact.Bind` and request the property for each Contact in question (*more service requests, but sometimes necessary*).

See [Viewing Extended Properties using EWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633697%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) for a full example on working with [Extended Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633691%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) in EWS.

#### Approach #1: *Retrieve Extended Property for all Contacts*

```cs
ExtendedPropertyDefinition propDef = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Common, "itemGUID", MapiPropertyType.String);
ItemView view = new ItemView(50) { PropertySet = new PropertySet(propDef) };
```

#### Approach #2: *Bind one contact at a time if you have a Contact ID*

```cs
ExtendedPropertyDefinition propDef = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Common, "itemGUID", MapiPropertyType.String);
Contact contact = Contact.Bind(service, contactID, new PropertySet(propDef));
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This got me what I needed. But as far as I can tell there is no ItemView constructor in that format so you have to do something like ItemView view = new ItemView(50); then view.PropertySet = new PropertySet... etc

Comment: @stefanlegg - Glad it helped! The `ItemView` constructor format is using the [Object Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx) format added in .NET 3.

Comment: Oh thanks! Do you happen to have an example of using FindItem with this extended property? I'm trying to do that with an item where i know the extended property but im getting 0 results, already changed the view thing like you suggested in that spot also

Comment: @stefanlegg - according to [this MSDN `FindItems` Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633633%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) - they perform the search filtering on the client side. This probably isn't optimal, but if all you are returning is the ContactIDs your service call will still be lightweight.

Comment: I figured it out, was just a matter of mismatching where the extended property was stored vs where i was looking